# Command Line Putty for SSH Tunnel

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to translate the GUI settings in Putty for establishing SSH tunnel to command line in Windows batch script. The first batch script establishes the port forwarding and tunnel ...

```
start putty -ssh root@10.54.20.98 -pw my_secure_pw -L 5555:10.54.22.104:5432 -L 2222:10.54.22.104:22
```

and the second batch script uses the tunnel ...

```
start putty -ssh localhost 5555
```

While the first script runs without error, I keep getting Putty Fatal Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection for the second one.

However, if I establish the tunnel using GUI as per snapshot below, and run the second script, there was no error and I can run the application accordingly.

Is there any missing configuration or option from the first script, if compare to the GUI?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the command line, the local ports tunnel to the remote IP 10.54.22.10**4** while the GUI variant uses 10.54.22.10**2** as destination.

Additionally, the destination's SSH daemon is probably listening on port 22, so you'd need to use the local port 2222 instead.